# Printing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Dear's all. 
Now I'm at the end of the first part of my project and now i need to print a voucher with few pre-printing words and 7 fields that comes from a dataset.
I try to use *rdlc file on which i made all the necesary layout very good, and the link was very good as well
But print NO
I did something in *.xaml file very dificult to put controls and make the links.
But lets say i will do it, for the moment i have a picture and a label with few words, and I'm trying to print it with the following lines

```
Dim myPrintDialog As PrintPreviewDialog = New PrintPreviewDialog
Dim myDocument As New PrintDocument
myPrintDialog.Document = myDocument
myPrintDialog.Document.DocumentName = "OrderVoucher.xaml"
myPrintDialog.ShowDialog()
```

But in the dialog I see only a blank page.
Of course I have a mistake in my mentality of building my code but I don't know where is that.
I also need to admit that is the first time in my life which I'm trying to print from Visual Studio 2010.
Now Please I need the best assistance you can give me.
P.S.
For the moment i want to print in my default Laser printer.
But in the final stage i will have to print in an Olivetti PR2 (Bank printer) which will be connected in the com: port.
That will be the day if I succeed :)

Comment: What did you used to do before you got involved in this project?

Comment: Olivetti printer?  Run for your life while you still can.  :-D

Comment: @Brad, :) Why you are so despert from this Printer? I was working in Olivetti Greece some Years ago and it was very good printer. At those times i have the programmer's guide book which now i lost it. But anyway i will try to handle it with a predefined document without any other adjustment. Wish me Luck :)

Comment: @Hans Passant, the process was all hand made, and steel is

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't use to work in the steel industry.  The communication problems make it hard to help you.  You're not close by a mile with what you've tried so far.  You really need to pick up a book and learn this.  You have no chance of getting printing working by trial and error.

Comment: @Hans Passant,No I'm working as developer in municipality of Elefsis in Greece. You have absolute right, but as far as see the situation here has two choices. A) Is to produce a predifined document and printed to PR2 thru a driver (Olivetti or IBM proprinterIII). B) Is to communicate with com port using the esc sequence. Thats why I'm looking the programmer's guide.

Comment: @Hans Passant, But for the moment I'm facing major issue, because I have a very good rdlc document and I can't converted in txt to printed. So let's solve the first issue and then we'll go to the other. What is your opinion? Can you assist me in the first step?

Answer (score 1):

Thats going to be a pretty long study session for you.Here's a great,great guide to learn basic printing:

[Guide to Print with Visual Studio 2010](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/74/04705328/DOWNLOAD/532874_both02_p2.pdf)